# No puedo hacer que la música de fondo de mi proyecto React.js con Redux Toolkit comience a sonar cuando se reenderiza la información

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es ponerle música de fondo a una página de pokemons, y que la música empiece a sonar en loop cuando carga la lista de pokemones.

Es posible parar la música y hacerla sonar manualmente con un componente `PauseButton`, pero no empieza a sonar por sí sola cuando me gustaría.

Este es mi componente Audio:

```javascript
    import React, { useEffect } from "react"
    import { useSelector } from "react-redux"
    import backgroundmusic from '../../assets/backgroundmusic.mp3'

    function Audio() {
        const music = useSelector(state => state.ui.music)
        
        useEffect(() => {
            const audioElement = document.getElementById('background-music');
            
            if (audioElement) {
              audioElement.volume = 0.5
            }
        }, [])

        return music && <audio
                id='background-music'
                src={backgroundmusic}
                autoPlay
                loop
            ></audio>
    }

    export { Audio }
```

Debería empezar a sonar la música cuando `music` sea `true`, pero sólo funciona si lo "pauso" y luego lo "despauso" utilizando el `PauseButton`:

```javascript
    import React from 'react';
    import { PauseOutlined, SoundOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons'
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
    import { setMusic } from '../../slices/UISlice'
    import './index.css'

    function PauseButton() {
        const dispatch = useDispatch()
        const music = useSelector(state => state.ui.music)

        function handleOnMusic() {
            dispatch(setMusic(!music))
        }

        return (
            <div className="music-wrapper" onClick={handleOnMusic}>
                {music ? <PauseOutlined className='music-icon'/> : <SoundOutlined className='music-icon'/>}
            </div>
        )
    }

    export { PauseButton }
```

Este es mi `AsyncThunk` en mi `DataSlice` que recoje la información de la API y actualiza el estado, `music` esta definida inicialmente como `false` en `UISlice`:

```javascript
export const getPokemonsWithDetails = createAsyncThunk(
        'data/getPokemonsWithDetails',
        async (gen, { dispatch }) => { 
            const pokemonsResults = await getPokemons(gen)

            const pokemonsDetails = await Promise.all (
                pokemonsResults.map(pokemon => {        
                    return getPokemonDetails(pokemon.url)
                })
            )

            //
            if (!localStorage.getItem('fav_pokemons')) {
                localStorage.setItem('fav_pokemons', JSON.stringify([]))
            }
                
            const favoriteList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fav_pokemons'))

            //
            const pokemonTypes = []

            pokemonsDetails.forEach( pokemon => {
                    const foundPokemon = favoriteList.find(LSpokemon => LSpokemon.id === pokemon.id)

                    if(foundPokemon){
                        pokemon.favorite = true
                    } else {
                        pokemon.favorite = false
                    }

                    pokemon.types.forEach(type => {
                        if(!pokemonTypes.includes(type.type.name)){
                            pokemonTypes.push(type.type.name)
                        }
                    }) 
                }
            )

            dispatch(setMusic(true)) // <===== SEGÚN YO, DEBERÍA EMPEZAR A SONAR LA MÚSICA AUTOMÁTICAMENTE
            dispatch(setTypes(pokemonTypes))
            dispatch(setPokemons(pokemonsDetails))
            dispatch(setShowedPokemons(pokemonsDetails))
            dispatch(setFavoritePokemons())
            dispatch(setLoading(false))
            dispatch(setSearching(false))
        }
    )
```

Comment: En el componente `Audio`, aqui `const music = useSelector(state => state.ui.music)` ¿Que valor inicial tiene el estado `music` en el primer render?, al llegar aqui `return music && <audio...` puedes verlo con un console.log ahi mismo.